# How to create custom scheduler in sugarcrm?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, crm, scheduler, sugarcrm

I am trying to create custom scheduler in sugarcrm using its documentation in

http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.9/Architecture/Job_Queue/Schedulers/Creating_Custom_Schedulers/.

I have created job label in path ./custom/Extension/modules/Schedulers/Ext/Language/en_us.final_test.php

with code

```
$mod_strings['LBL_FINAL_TEST'] = 'Final Test Of Scheduler';
```

and created job function in path 
./custom/Extension/modules/Schedulers/Ext/ScheduledTasks/final_test.php
with code

```
<?php
 array_push($job_strings, 'final_test');
 $GLOBALS['log']->fatal('my fatal message inside function');//this works
 function final_test(){
     $GLOBALS['log']->fatal('my fatal message inside function');//this don't
     return true;
 }
?>
```

Here if i put

```
$GLOBALS['log']->fatal('my fatal message outside function');
```

outside the function then it runs I get message in log file. But 
when i put

```
$GLOBALS['log']->fatal('my fatal message inside function');
```

inside the function then this doesn't work and i don't get any log.

Which part am I doing wrong? where can I get proper tutorial to develop custom scheduler for sugarcrm?

**NOTE: I have set the scheduler to run at every minute**

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that your Schedulers are not running at all.
(Your "outside" message probably only makes it into the log whenever the file is loaded in general)

Make sure your cron jobs are configured correctly, as they are required to call Sugar's Scheduler Engine every minute: https://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Schedulers/Introduction_to_Cron_Jobs/

If you don't feel like setting them up, you could also manually trigger Schedulers with `php -f cron.php` (on web service account e.g. `sudo -u www-data php -f cron.php` if on Debian linux) in your Sugar directory.

If your function's output still doesn't appear in the logs:

- Check if your current function is in `custom/modules/Schedulers/Ext/ScheduledTasks/scheduledtasks.ext.php`. If not, run a Quick Repair & Rebuild.
- Check file permissions on the log file
- Check your PHP log/output for errors. E.g. in case you defined a function called "final_test" somewhere else already, PHP would terminate with a fatal error due to a function name collision.

Comment: Thank you. My cron jobs was not configured correctly.The issue was that I wasn't mentioning the version of php in it. As of now it is running perfectly.